# ASP.NET Core: how can I change the PubTmp directory?

Tags: asp.net-core, path, azure-web-app-service, visual-studio-2022

I have an ASP.NET Core web app. The app builds and runs fine on my machine. However, when I try to publish to my Azure App Service web app, I have errors.

The errors are happening because some of the paths to files in the `wwwroot` directory are too long. The failure is happening when the files are copied to the following temp directory:

```
\obj\Release\net8.0\PubTmp\Out\
```

How can I configure the project to use a different directory for this part of the publishing process?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you please share your code repo? What are the errors you are getting?

Comment: I can't share the code repo. The error is: C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.StaticWebAssets\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.StaticWebAssets.Publish.targets(150,5): Warning MSB3026: Could not copy "C:\[project-path]\wwwroot\[path-to-resource]" to "C:\[project-path]\obj\Release\net8.0\PubTmp\Out\wwwroot\[path-to-resource]". Beginning retry 1 in 1000ms. Could not find a part of the path 'C:\[project-path]\obj\Release\net8.0\PubTmp\Out\wwwroot\[path-to-resource]'. This only happens with the longest filenames, so I am positive that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> some of the paths to files in the `wwwroot` directory are too long.

To copy the files which are in `wwwroot` folder to a new folder, use the below configuration in `.csproj` file.

```cs
 <Target Name="CustomDeployment" AfterTargets="Publish">
   <Exec Command="xcopy /s /y $(PublishDir)\wwwroot\*.* $(PublishDir)\wwwroot\TempFolder\" />
 </Target>
```

***Output:***
[image]

> The failure is happening when the files are copied to the following temp directory:

To copy the files which are in `Release\net8.0\PubTmp\Out` to a new Temp Folder, check the below configuration.

I have added `BaseOutputPath` and `PubTmpPath` in `.csproj` file.

```cs
 <PropertyGroup>
    <BaseOutputPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\obj\TempFolder</BaseOutputPath>   <PubTmpPath>$(BaseOutputPath)$(Configuration)\$(TargetFramework)\PubTmp\</PubTmpPath>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

- Now you can see the files in `PubTmp` are copied to a new `NewTemp` folder.

[image]